# timeago jquery plugin problem

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am using timeago jquery plugin to show nice dates for the users, The problem I found is that my server is 6 hours far from my time zone, so if I added a record in the db and it save the current time, it saves the current server date time, so when I get the date again I see it late 6 hours than it should look.

For example I have this table in db:
Id, Name, CreatedOn
I insert a new record and Created is automatically get the current date using my server side c# code.

When I get this record to show in the browser I see it 6 hours late.

How to solve this issue, from the server side or the client side will be better and how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not save "current time", rather save UTC equivalent of current time.

Send this UTC time to browser and let the browser to convert in specific local time.

Comment: how the browser will convert?

Comment: http://techrepublic.com/article/convert-the-local-time-to-another-time-zone-with-this-javascript/6016329016329

Comment: http://emplementation.blogspot.com/2010/11/displaying-timestamps-in-clientsviewers.html is also a good resource.ood resource.

Comment: @Amr: Did it worked out? I was replying from mobile so could not post any code sample then, but now I can. Please reply me if you need further assistance on this topic.